# Spring+SpringSecurity 2 to Spring+SpringSecurity 3 migration error

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a problem that keep me busy the all day, and therefore, I need help.
I'm migrating a project from Spring 2 Spring Security 2 to Spring 3 Spring Security 3.
Everything goes fine, except that I have an exception when I launch the application :

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#3' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [3]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#3': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#55401592' of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#55401592': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3885c37f' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3885c37f': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.cachingUserDetailsService(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.telemis.web.admin.security.TmsAuthenticationProvider] for bean with name 'tmAuthenticationProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/userdetails/UserDetailsService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1760)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#3': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#55401592' of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#55401592': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3885c37f' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3885c37f': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.cachingUserDetailsService(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.telemis.web.admin.security.TmsAuthenticationProvider] for bean with name 'tmAuthenticationProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/userdetails/UserDetailsService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1077)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:981)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#55401592': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3885c37f' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3885c37f': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.cachingUserDetailsService(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.telemis.web.admin.security.TmsAuthenticationProvider] for bean with name 'tmAuthenticationProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/userdetails/UserDetailsService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1077)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:981)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3885c37f' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3885c37f': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.cachingUserDetailsService(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.telemis.web.admin.security.TmsAuthenticationProvider] for bean with name 'tmAuthenticationProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/userdetails/UserDetailsService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1077)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:981)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3885c37f': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.cachingUserDetailsService(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.telemis.web.admin.security.TmsAuthenticationProvider] for bean with name 'tmAuthenticationProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/userdetails/UserDetailsService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:603)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    ... 96 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.cachingUserDetailsService(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.telemis.web.admin.security.TmsAuthenticationProvider] for bean with name 'tmAuthenticationProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/userdetails/UserDetailsService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:592)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.telemis.web.admin.security.TmsAuthenticationProvider] for bean with name 'tmAuthenticationProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/userdetails/UserDetailsService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1347)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:437)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:431)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1184)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.getBeansOfType(UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.getUserDetailsService(UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.cachingUserDetailsService(UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/userdetails/UserDetailsService
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:265)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1270)
    ... 117 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.userdetails.UserDetailsService
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 128 more
```

I search for a few hours now, but I can't find the problem.
I know what a NoClassDefFoundError is, but I checked everything, my jars seems ok, my dependencies are fine, but I always have this f... exception.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Seb

Comment: Slt fieu comment va ?

Answer (score 0):

Hereunder is my applicationcontext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
        >

    <bean id="appConfiguration" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/config/AppConfiguration"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="externalStatisticsResources" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/config/ExternalStatisticsResources"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="serversArchiver" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/config/ServersArchiver"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="propertiesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <ref bean="appConfiguration"/>
                <ref bean="externalStatisticsResources"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="languageHolder" name="languageHolder" class="com.telemis.web.stat.LanguageHolder" scope="session">
        <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
        <property name="language" value="${stat.language}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="languageController" class="com.telemis.web.stat.actions.LanguageController">
        <property name="languageHolder" ref="languageHolder"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="statisticHolder" name="statisticHolder" class="com.telemis.web.stat.StatisticsHolder">
        <property name="dbDriver" value="${stat.db.driver}"/>
        <property name="language" ref="languageHolder"/>
        <property name="externalCategoriesFile" value="${stat.external.categories}"/>
        <property name="externalStatisticsFolder" value="${stat.external.statistics}"/>
        <property name="serverArchiverStore" ref="serversArchiver"/>
    </bean>

    <alias name="statisticHolder" alias="ServerArchiver"/>


    <bean id="restApplication" class="com.telemis.web.stat.rest.StatApplication">
        <property name="statisticsHolder" ref="statisticHolder"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- 
    <bean id="AdminRemoteClient" class="com.telemis.web.admin.remote.rmi.AdminRemoteClientImpl">
        <property name="serverAddress" value="${tms.address}"/>
        <property name="serverPort" value="${tms.port}"/>
        <property name="serversArchiver" value=""/>
    </bean>
     -->

    <bean id="loginController" class="com.telemis.web.admin.security.LoginController">
    </bean>

    <!-- security -->
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/login/check" />
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/assets/**" />
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/css/**" />

    <security:http access-denied-page="/login/access_denied" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
        <!--
        <security:form-login login-page="/login/check"
                             default-target-url="/index.jsp"
                             authentication-failure-url="/login/check?login_error=1"/>
                              -->

        <security:intercept-url pattern='/**' access='ROLE_STATISTICS'/>

<!--
        <security:concurrent-session-control
                exception-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login/check"/>
-->

        <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login/check"/>

        <security:anonymous/>
        <security:http-basic/>
        <security:remember-me/>

        <security:custom-filter ref="tmAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    </security:http>


    <!-- Telemis Authentication provider, validate user credentials against
         a TMS server -->

    <bean id="tmAuthenticationProvider" class="com.telemis.web.admin.security.TmsAuthenticationProvider">
<!--    <bean id="myAuthenticationProvider" class="com.telemis.web.admin.security.TmsUserDetailsService"> -->
<!--        <property name="adminRemoteClient" ref="AdminRemoteClient"/> -->
        <property name="requiredRoles">
            <list>
                <value>ROLE_STATISTICS</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--  Custom entry point supporting redirect URL depending on the 
          authentication failure exceptions -->

    <bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" class="com.telemis.web.admin.security.TmAuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login/check" />
        <property name="forceHttps" value="false" />
        <property name="defaultExceptionMapping" value="/login/check?login_error=generic" />
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="com.telemis.web.admin.security.ServerUnavailableException">/login/check?login_error=serverUnavailable</prop>
                <prop key="org.springframework.security.BadCredentialsException">/login/check?login_error=badCredentials</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Get authentication information and create the AuthenticationToken 
         containing the user/pwd + target server information -->

    <bean id="tmAuthenticationProcessingFilter" class="com.telemis.web.admin.security.TmAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler" />
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler" />
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="tmAuthenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="successHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="failureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login/check?login_error=1" />
    </bean>

    <!--  Just create an alias for the authentication manager. -->
    <!--<security:authentication-manager alias="tmAuthenticationManager"/>-->

    <security:authentication-manager id="tmAuthenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="tmAuthenticationProvider"  />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!-- 
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"/>
       -->


</beans>
```